# Maven Versions plugin skips some dependencies

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I experienced that the Maven Versions plugin does not check every version property when running `mvn versions:display-property-updates`. It is noticeable that most of them are plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some dependencies defined in profiles. These can only be checked by the versions plugin if these profiles are also activated.

```
mvn -Pmyprofile versions:display-property-updates
```